# iphone-startup screen: any way to manage control time(3-4 sec) in displaying Default.png

Tags: iphone

i have used simple Default.png for startup screen.and it is working fine.But it disappears very soonIt want it to be on screen atleast 3-4 seconds .Any way to use timer or i have to use an image view for splash screen.
While searching on forums i also found that it is discouraged in Apple HUman Interface guidelines.
Help please!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this:
http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/application-delegate-for-the-first-iphone-application-explained.aspx

i think you are looking for some delegate like:

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

You also can add the same Default Image Again when the application become active and remove it once you're ready to go.

Comment: @iphone_bharat and @Ahmad:-Hi.i have found one solution to do this using sleep(2) in applicationdidfinish in my appdelegate.and getting what i want to do.I also appreciate your answers and want to discuss both of you if i am right and trying your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the initial view of the app -- the actual app's view, not Default.png -- a full-screen window with an imageview containing the Default.png image, with a timer that hides it after whatever delay you'd like. When the app starts up it will display Default.png, and when it actually becomes active the same image will be in place, producing a seamless transition, which you'll hide on your schedule.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps for ur question

1. Add an imageview in ur mainwindow.nib to ur window and set its image as "urDefault.png"
2. In ur AppDelegate.m

   `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [self performSelector:@selector(removesplashimage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

   return YES;
   }

   -(void)removesplashimage
   {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7]; 
    [imview setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
   }