# Launch Image Screen Time

Tags: ios, ipad, launch

Thanks in advance for taking the time to give this a look.  I am a rookie so please forgive me if this is programing 101, but after reading several references and searching online, I'm not coming up with an answer.

Is there a way to control the length of time the launch image is displayed prior to the initiation of the app?

Thanks again for any and all help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone-startup screen: any way to manage control time(3-4 sec) in displaying Default.png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469841/iphone-startup-screen-any-way-to-manage-control-time3-4-sec-in-displaying-def)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a splash screen for longer on an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553336/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-longer-on-an-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to manually code a launch image to come up at the start for a designated time and then switch the views around. If you do it the way you're going about it then the time it stays on the screen for is predetermined.

Comment: I am a newbie.  Is this difficult to do?  Recommendations or referral to some literature that can give me some direction?  Thanks for the help!